# .net c++ timer_tick function does not work

Tags: .net, timer, managed-c++

I created a button to start the timer and the interval of timer is 1000.
I added a timer_Tick() event handler but it is not working, I dont understand the reason.

Here is my code:

```
void button1_Click(...)
{
    this->timer->Start();
    for( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
        Thread::Sleep(1000);
    this->timer->Stop();
}

void timer_Tick(...)
{
    this->textBox->Text = "njmk"; // only to handle while debugging but it is not handled
}
```

Note: I added this:

```
this->timer->Tick += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::timer_Tick);
```

**EDIT :**

OK, I will try to explain my problem clearly.
I have a main form and in the status strip I have a `toolstripprogressbar`.
When I click a button, a function will start parsing a file and the progress bar must show the progress of the function. So here is my code:

```
void button_click(...)
{
    this->progressBar->Visible = true;
    this->backGroundWorker->RunWorkerAsync();
}

void backGorundWorker_DoWork(...)
{
    this->timer->Start();
    ParseFunction(); // it takes about two minute
    this->timer->Stop();
}

void timer_Tick(...)
{
    this->bacGroundWorker->ReportProgress(5);
}

void backGroundWorker_ProgressChanged(...)
{
    this->progressBar->Value += e->ProgressPercentage();
}
void backGroundWorker_RunWorkerComplete(...)
{
    this->progressBar->Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: You don't need timer to update progressbar: you need to do inside your `ParseFunction()`. Take care: in debug you can have some error because you try to update as UI object from another thread. If you run directly your EXE this error is not raised; to solve it during debug you use `if ... InvokeRequired...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because you're making the thread (UI thread) sleep for 1000 * 1000 milliseconds (~16 minutes):

```
void button1_Click(...)
{
    this->timer->Start();
    for( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
        Thread::Sleep(1000);
    this->timer->Stop();
}
```

That's why it can't update the textbox content.

Comment: Seems exactly what I've already answered ;) But yes, you're right, that's the problem

Comment: Ok, you are right. So, how can I get time while a function running.I mean, I call a function and let say it takes 1 minute, I want to execute another function every 10 seconds. How can I do this?

Comment: @user983924 It's not clear what you are trying to do. Please rephrase that then add it to your question.

Comment: @user983924 If I understand you correctly, at the end of the function that takes one minute (I'm assuming you want them to be executed in that order) set the interval of the timer to `10000ms` (10 seconds) and on each tick make a call to the function you want to execute every 10 seconds. You can also use threads, but they are a little bit tricky to get right.

Comment: @Marco I didn't give enough time for SO to pop up the "Load new answers" message, That's why I posted my answer. But since we're both right, I gave you an up vote from me.

Comment: @Nacereddine: thank you, I'm glad, but there was not any problem for me :D

Comment: @user983924: if you want to execute more than one time consuming function, execute them in separate threads (not in the main one). If you need to synchronyze them you can use mutexes, semaphores and all the objects .net gives you

Comment: @user983924: remember, in main thread you can execute other functions, but while it's busy it won't update user interface...

Comment: Thanks guys, it works fine now. I just moved the 'this->timer->Start();' and 'this->timer->Stop();' from backGorundWorker_DoWork() to button_Click() function

Answer (score 1):

When you use `this->textBox->Text = "njmk"` in timer event, main thread should update textbox text; but you're making main thread to sleep, so it's not free to update textbox!!
Remember that UI objects are updated from main thread!
This is the reason for which we use multithread if we have to run long procedures and let our window to be redrawn and respond to user.